# OnePlus 5T on Oxygen Os ignores the specified color of the navigation bar

Tags: java, android, colors, navigationbar

The problem is that on the OnePlus 5T running Oxygen Os on 8.0, the system ignores the specified colors of the navigation bar in applications. On the other devices, including OnePlus 5, there is no such problem.
I set the color like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/actionbar_color</item>
</style>
```

The only way to color navbar in the required color is to set it manuall:

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(con, R.color.actionbar_color));
```

Is there a way to specify color through resources, not by code?

BTW, let's say I want to make an application that in the same way will color the navigation bar in other applications in which the system ignores the developer's specified color. Is it real from this my application to access another application and run this one line of code?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue and I had to resolve it by assigning color as follows:

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.rgb(27, 27, 27)));
```